# How to implement immutable cache in Scala?

Tags: scala, caching, concurrency, future

Suppose I have a server, which calls a time consuming function `slow: Int => String` upon a client request. If `slow` does not return within the `timeout` the server returns an error to the client.

```
def trySlow(timeout: Duration)(id: Int): Try[String] = {
  val fut = Future(slow(id))
  try {
    Await.ready(fut, timeout).value match {
      case Some(r) => r
      case None => Failure(new TimeoutException()) // should not happen
    }
  } catch {
     case e: TimeoutException => Failure(e)
  } 
}
```

Now I'd like to cache the futures so that multiple threads calling `trySlow` with the same `id` will wait for the same future.

I am going to use a *mutable* concurrent [TrieMap](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.collection.concurrent.TrieMap) to implement a *singleton* cache.

```
case class CacheEntry (
  future: Future[String], 
  start: Long = System.currentTimeMillis() // need it to clean the cache
) 

type Cache = TrieMap[Int, CacheEntry]

def trySlow(timeout: Duration, cache: Cache)(id: Int): Try[String] = {

  val fut = cache.getOrElseUpdate(id,  CacheEntry(Future(slow(id))))

  ... // as in above
}
```

Does it make sense ? How to do it with *immutable* *non-singleton* cache ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use only things within scala collections, scala.collection.concurrent.TrieMap is a decent choice. However, please be aware that TrieMap#getOrElseUpdate had a [thread safety bug](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7943) that was only fixed recently in 2.11.6.

If you can afford the additional dependency, [guava cache](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CachesExplained) is quite good for writing such caches. Especially if you want entries in the cache to expire in some way.

Regarding the API of your cache: assuming you are talking about pure functions, the cache generator should be just a thing that takes a function T => U and returns a function T => U

So something along these lines:

```
object Cached {
  def apply[T,U](f: T=>U): T=>U = { ??? }
}
```

Usage:

```
def slow(id: Int): Try[String] = ??? // something complex including futures, timeouts etc.
val fast: Int => Try[String] = Cached(slow)
```

The caching API should not have to know anything about the function being cached, other than that you expect it to be pure.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning that bug. I am running on 2.11.6 now so it won't be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you use guava libraries in general.
(https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)

Like Rüdiger Klaehn mentioned **cache** is a good place to start.